# Combine 2 Worksheet_Change events

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Worksheet_Change event subs that work perfectly on their own, however I need to combine these to test the conditions of either of two ranges "G2" or G3". I have tried all the options in search, but just cannot get this to work. I would appreciate any assistance or advise.
Below are the two Subs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("G2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

          Dim lr As Long
          lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

          Range("Z7:Z" & lr) = "=ISERROR(MATCH(G$2,B7:O7,0))"
          Range("Z7", Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter 1, False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Call activate_button_31


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("G3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

          Dim lr As Long
          lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

          Range("Q7:Q" & lr) = "=ISERROR(MATCH(G$3,B7:O7,0))"
          Range("Q7", Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter 1, False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Call activate_button_40


End Sub
```

Please let me know should you require any further information.

Kind Regards

Coenie

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("Z7:Z" & lr) = "=ISERROR(MATCH(G$2,B7:O7,0))"
        Range("Z7", Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter 1, False
        Call activate_button_31

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("G3")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("Q7:Q" & lr) = "=ISERROR(MATCH(G$3,B7:O7,0))"
        Range("Q7", Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter 1, False
        Call activate_button_40
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to combine the routines:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lr As Long

    On Error GoTo Terminate
    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo Terminate
    xlQuiet True
    lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G2")) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("Z7:Z" & lr)
            .Formula = "=ISERROR(MATCH(G$2,B7:O7,0))"
            .AutoFilter 1, False
        End With
        xlQuiet False
        Call activate_button_31
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("G3")) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("Q7:Q" & lr)
            .Formula = "=ISERROR(MATCH(G$3,B7:O7,0))"
            .AutoFilter 1, False
        End With
        xlQuiet False
        Call activate_button_40
    End If

Terminate:
    If err Then
        Debug.Print "Error", err.Number, err.Description
        err.clear
    End If
    xlQuiet False

End Sub

Private Sub xlQuiet(Optional ByVal b As Boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = Not b
        .EnableEvents = Not b
    End With
End Sub
```